# Bluetooth headsets connect to PC but not sound in Windows 11

Tags: windows, audio, bluetooth, headset

So about a month ago my wireless headsets (have two) both stopped playing sound in Windows 11.

They work when in headset mode, but not as headphones. I've tried everything, uninstalling Bluetooth drivers (twice), removing and repairing headsets in Bluetooth.

When I do test device I can see the sound meter moving, but nothing is coming through the headphones.

The only thing I notice is that in the sound options the default format is greyed out.

[image: Sound options]

Answer (score 0):

Check Default Playback Device:

Right-click on the speaker icon in the system tray and select "Open Sound settings."
Under the Output section, check if your wireless headsets are selected as the default playback device.
Update Audio Drivers:

Ensure that your audio drivers are up-to-date. Visit the website of your headset manufacturer or your computer's manufacturer to download and install the latest drivers.
Device Manager:

Open Device Manager (you can do this by right-clicking the Start button and selecting Device Manager).
Locate your Bluetooth device and your audio device under "Audio inputs and outputs."
Right-click on each and choose "Update driver."
Bluetooth Troubleshooter:

Open Settings and go to Update & Security.
Select Troubleshoot from the left pane.
Run the Bluetooth troubleshooter.
Check for Windows Updates:

Make sure your operating system is up-to-date. Go to Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update and check for updates.
Default Format Options:

Although the default format is grayed out, you might still be able to change it. Right-click on your audio device in the Sound settings, choose Properties, and navigate to the Advanced tab. Check if you can change the default format from there.
Reset Bluetooth Settings:

In Settings, go to Devices and select Bluetooth & other devices.
Under the "Related settings" section, click on "More Bluetooth options."
In the Bluetooth Settings window, go to the "Options" tab, and click on "Reset Bluetooth."
Check for Interference:

Other electronic devices or Wi-Fi networks may interfere with Bluetooth signals. Try using your headsets in a different location to rule out interference issues.
System Restore:

If the issue started after a specific event (such as a software installation), you might consider using System Restore to revert your system to a state where the headsets were working.
If none of these steps resolve the issue, there might be a more complex problem that requires further investigation. You may want to contact Microsoft Support or the support channels of your headset manufacturer for more specific assistance.

Comment: Looks like an output from chatgpt.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips but still the same, had sort of tried all those before.

I should note that anything wired is fine, I have usb-c connector for some wired earphones and they were fine as does the audio plugs on the PC. 
It is purely a bluetooh issue and have tried 3 devices now and none work. Its as if there is some block between the sound on the PC and getting to the bluetooth devices.